# What is the difference between these two methods of achieving a function call?

Tags: c++

I'm slightly confused about what the difference between these two code examples are in `C++`. If anyone could explain it, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
class abc {
    void foo();
};

void abc::foo() {

}
```

versus something like:

```
class abc {
    void foo() {
        //func
    }
};
```

Comment: Slight nitpicking: There's no *call* in the code you show, and the question isn't really about calling the functions (it's about function definitions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second alternative implicitly marks the function as [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), which means you can have it in a header file that is included into multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

The first example would break the [*One Definition Rule*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) if it were part of such a header file.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case the function is by default inline but in other case you need to mention explicitly if you want it inline.
Read about inline-
[Go there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline)